# Code injection for Android

Tags: android, orm, dexmaker

I want to write an ORM for Android as my final project.
My first idea is to inject code for each get and set.
Unfortunately I found a lot of posts saying there is no way to inject code in Android.

On the other hand I found "Dexmaker" to generate code on runtime.

My question is: Is it possible to somehow inject code in Android (by "Dexmaker" or anything else)?

If not how to do it ?

I also thought about reflections but I am afraid that it will be to slow.

Thanks in advance.

Edit

Simon: 
Yes by ORM I ment object relational mapping.
I want to create a general framework. How else I could do this than not by code injection ?

Comment: Do you mean object relational mapping?  Or something else?  Also, what is it about your design that requires you to use code injection?

Comment: Relflection under Android is dog slow.  That's a non-starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject code using Dexmaker. The project site has a `HelloWorldMaker` example that generates a class and then loads it.

You may find the performance of runtime code generation to be unsatisfying however. Projects like [Dagger](http://square.github.com/dagger/) have had better success metaprogramming with code generation.